# Array into template in Alfresco rules script

Tags: freemarker, alfresco

I have a question for Alfresco Community v4.0.0

- I create content rule,
- select execute script,
- and in the script call processTemplate(ScriptNode template, array args)

How do I get an array into template? Args contains only key - value (String).

Thanks in advance for any advice or help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting something like "Expected extended hash. args.array evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar", am I right?

If so, I'm afraid you can not get this working with scripts called from content rules, because there are no [wrappers](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html) for complex datatypes, so this is the reason only String (and other scalars) is accepted.

You have two choices:

1. Alter alfresco code, which wraps objects and sends them into processTemplate() and build whole system (maybe more info on this you can find in [my older blogpost](http://www.shmoula.cz/more-on-invoking-scripts-in-alfresco/))
2. Put an array into processTemplate() and in template read it like a string and then parse it - arrays looks like [val1,val2,val3], so refer to [freemarker documentation for string functions](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_string.html) and do something like this (ugly, but fast solution):

   ```
   <#list args.array?split(",") as value>
       hereRemoveFirstAndLastSquareBracketFrom(${value});
   </#list>
   ```

Edit: If anyone interested, I just raised a bug in [Alfresco JIRA](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-14845)

Comment: There *is* complex data-type wrapping in FreeMarker. Like arrays are supported by it. Something is wrong with the wrapper that Alfresco uses if you indeed get arrays as strings.

Comment: Freemarker in Alfresco should work just fine with complex types like Arrays and Hashes (a lot of the core of Alfresco depends on that!). It sounds like you might have found a bug, if so [issues.alfresco.com](http://issues.alfresco.com) is the place to report it so it gets fixed!

Comment: Hashes and Arrays work fine with standard webscripts, but not with scripts executed by content rules. I agree that sounds lika a bug, I'll fill JIRA and check what to patch. ;-)